# How can I use different margins for the title page in Quarto pdf book?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I am creating PDF book using Quarto in RStudio. I use geometry package to specify margins in it. In particular, I want the margins on the title page different from other pages. The title page margins should be

```
geometry:
      - top=25.4mm
      - left=25.4mm
      - right=25.4mm
      - bottom=25.4mm
```

But I want different left-margin on all the other pages. The margins on all the other pages should be

```
geometry:
      - top=25.4mm
      - left=38.1mm
      - right=25.4mm
      - bottom=25.4mm
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [template partials](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html), you can specify different geometry for the title page and after the title page, you can restore the geometry for other pages.

To do that you need to create a `before-body.tex` file as a partial latex template and inside that file, specify the new margin for the title page as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75698/261065).

**before-body.tex**

```
$if(has-frontmatter)$
\frontmatter
$endif$

%------------------------------------------------
% Declaring new geometry for the title page only.
\newgeometry{margin=25.4mm}
%------------------------------------------------

$if(title)$
$if(beamer)$
\frame{\titlepage}
$else$
\maketitle
$endif$

%-----------------------------------------------
% Ending the declared geometry for the title page
% and restore the geometry for other pages
\restoregeometry
%-----------------------------------------------

$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$
$endif$
```

Then to add this template, use the `template-partials` option in `_quarto.yml`

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "Different Margins for Title Page"
  author: "Shafee"
  date: "7/31/2022"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    include-in-header: 
      text: \usepackage[showframe, top=25.4mm, left=38.1mm, right=25.4mm, bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}
    template-partials:
      - before-body.tex
```

Doing so you will have different margin for title page than all other pages for you book.

---

**Title Page**

[image: Title page]

**Other page**

[image: Other page]

---

**Note that** I have used the `showframe` option of geometry package just to show that the margin changed. When you are done with testing with margin remove that option.

```
include-in-header: 
      text: \usepackage[top=25.4mm, left=38.1mm, right=25.4mm, bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This worked perfectly for me. I had to tweak the code because I had also added a packages.tex in my code to ensure that the whole report uses Times New Roman font. Thanks again.